# Reason on full rankedness at even dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix family 
$M_n=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&\dots&1&1\\
-1&0&1&\dots&1&1\\
-1&-1&0&\dots&1&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
-1&-1&-1&\dots&0&1\\
-1&-1&-1&\dots&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$ where $M_{i,i}=0$ and $M_{i,j}=-M_{j,i}=1$ if $j>i$.

Why is the rank of the matrix $M_n$ in family always $2\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$?

Answer (score 0):

First, we have the following claim, which is not hard to prove:

**Claim.** The span of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ have the same dimension as the span of vectors $v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3, \ldots, v_{m-1}-v_m,v_m+v_1$.

We apply the following claim to the columns of the matrix. Hence, it suffices to find the rank of the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0&\dots&0&0&1\\
-1&-1&0&\dots&0&0&0\\
0&-1&-1&\dots&0&0&0\\
0&0& -1 & \dots &0&0&0 \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&-1&-1&0\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Denote the columns of $A$ from left to right as $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.
Let see if these columns are linearly independent or not. 
Consider $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iv_i=0$.
For each row $i =2, \ldots, n$ we find 
$\alpha_{i-1}+\alpha_i=0$. From these equations, we obtain that 
$\alpha_1=\alpha_3= \alpha_5= \ldots= \alpha_{2\left \lfloor (n-1)/2
\right \rfloor +1}$ and $\alpha_2=\alpha_4= \ldots =
\alpha_{2 \left \lfloor n/2\right \rfloor}$. We have not consider the first row, which gives $\alpha_1-\alpha_n=0$.

If $n$ is even and from $\alpha_1=\alpha_{n}$, we obtain 
$\alpha_i=0$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. This follows $v_1, \ldots, v_n$
is linearly independent, which gives the dimension of $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then surely the columns are not linearly independent, as 
we can choose nonzero $\alpha_i$'s as follow: $\alpha_1=\alpha_3= \ldots= \alpha_n=1$ and
$\alpha_2=\alpha_4= \ldots = \alpha_{n-1}=-1$. To show that dimension of
the columns $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is $n-1$, we take out any column,
WLOG say $v_n$, and then show that $v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ are 
linearly independent. This can be done similarly as above 
by writing simple equation for each row.

Thus, our final answer is indeed $2 \left \lfloor \frac n2 \right \rfloor$.